# HTML canvas position

Tags: image, canvas, position

I have an image inside a canvas, and I'm trying to place an "x" on a specific place on the image (not always the same place), but the "x" always appears slightly to the right of where it should go. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us how you did it, so we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: This is a simplified version:

Comment: var canvas=document.getElementById("can");
var gc=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();   

img.src = "quad.jpg";


canvas.addEventListener('click',test);
gc.font="30px Arial";
gc.fillStyle="red";

canvas.width=window.screen.width;
canvas.height=(window.screen.height/10)*7;
img.width=canvas.width/2;
img.height=(canvas.height/10)*7;

coorX=img.x;
coorY=(forF1*refH)-refH;
gc.fillText("X",coorX,100);

Comment: Sorry, it was a silly mistake; the same function appeared twice with different values.